# Netezza procedure skip null variable in loop

Tags: netezza

We have an SP that generates a list of tables for migration.  During processing of the list of tables, there are instances where tables originally in the list are dropped.  The SP raises an exception and exits when encountering 'table not found' conditions.

Here is the code:

```
SQL_STATEMENT1 := 'SELECT * FROM ...';

FOR REC1 IN EXECUTE SQL_STATEMENT1
LOOP
   SQL_STATEMENT2 := 'SELECT * FROM ...';

   FOR REC2 IN EXECUTE SQL_STATEMENT2
   LOOP
   ...
```

I'm looking to validate REC1 in SQL_STATEMENT2 to verify it's neither null or an empty string.  If it is, I want to skip that instance of REC1 and move to the next.  Below does not appear to be the answer:

```
IF SQL_STATEMENT2 IS NULL THEN                                          
CONTINUE                                                                
END IF;
```

or

```
IF SQL_STATEMENT2 IS NULL THEN                                          
EXIT FOR                                                                
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a small possibility that one of the tables from the original list is dropped between the time you generate the outer list and the time the inner statement is executed, I see no immediate way of preventing it from failing. Even if there is only one table on the outer ‘list’...

You need to handle that particular error inside the SP in a benign way.